# onchange event not fire when the change come from another function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an input text that get his value from a Javascript function (a timer with countdown).

I want to raise an event when the input text is 0 ,so I am using the change eventListener.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to raise the event when the change is coming from javascript function.

How can I force the change event to work, even if the change is coming from Javascript and not from the user?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents):

> **change**
>   The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus. This event is valid for INPUT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA. element.

When you modify the text input's value through code, the change event will not be fired because there is no focus change. You can trigger the event yourself though with [`createEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.createEvent) and [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.dispatchEvent), for example:

```
el = document.getElementById('x');
ev = document.createEvent('Event');
ev.initEvent('change', true, false);
el.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

And a live version: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/nH8CH/

Comment: This won't work if you use any modern event listening method; it will only work if you use the old `onchange` property. You should use the DOM events API to fire events.

Comment: @Delan: Can you tell that I haven't done raw JavaScript for a long time? I'll patch it up.

Answer (score 4):

it's 2018 now and seems that initEvent() is deprecated:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent

i think you can trigger the event in a one-liner now:
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));

Answer (score 3):

In the function that changes the value, manually fire a `change` event.

```
var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
e.initEvent('change', false, false);
some_input_element.dispatchEvent(e);
```

Comment: Does it need to be `HTMLEvents`? The jQuery version apparently uses `Event` and the only difference I can see is DOM level 2 versus level 3.

Comment: As far as I know, `HTMLEvents`, `Event` and `Events` are synonymous.

Comment: [`Event`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-Event) seems to be the official one, `Events` is probably around in some browsers to match the `hasFeature` pluralization.

Answer (score 1):

A more reusable option :

```
function simulate_event(eventName, element) {
    // You could set this into the prototype as a method.
    var event;

    if (document.createEvent) {
        event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
    } else {
        event = document.createEventObject();
        event.eventType = eventName;
    };

    event.eventName = eventName;

    if (document.createEvent) {
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else {
        element.fireEvent("on" + event.eventName, event);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply redefine the "value" property of the node, using `getAttribute("value")` and `setAttribute("value", newValue)`, in the getters and setters, as well as dispatch the "change" event at the end of the setter. For example:

```js
myNode.onchange = e => console.log("Changed!", e.target.value);

Object.defineProperty(myNode, "value", {
  get: () => myNode.getAttribute("value"),
  set(newValue) {
    myNode.setAttribute("value", newValue);
    myNode.dispatchEvent(new Event("change")); //or define the event earlier, not sure how much of a performance difference it makes though
  }
})

var i = 0;
setTimeout(function changeIt() {
    if(i++ < 10) {
        myNode.value = i;
        setTimeout(changeIt, 1000);
    }
}, 1)
```

```html
<input id="myNode">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `change`, you can use `keypress` event instead.

This is because the `change` event is not meant to fire until it is not focused anymore - when you click out of the input tag.