# Why does dynamically changing a checkbox not trigger a form change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this snippet of javascript/jQuery to change a check box.
http://jsfiddle.net/johnhoffman/crF93/

Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
       if ($("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked') == "checked")
           $("input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr('checked');
       else
           $("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', 'checked');
       return false;
    });

    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){ 
        console.log("Checkbox changed.");            
    });    
});​
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<a href="#">Change CheckBox</a>​
```

Interestingly, clicking the link alters the text box, but does not trigger the form change event that calls the function that logs a message in Chrome Web Developer Console. Why? How do I make it do that?

Comment: ["The change event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus."](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents) No focus change means no change event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [onchange event not fire when the change come from antoher function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055729/onchange-event-not-fire-when-the-change-come-from-antoher-function)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to trigger the change event, `.trigger('change')`, so that event knows that a change took place.

From http://api.jquery.com/change/:

> **Description:** Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.
>
> This method is a shortcut for `.on( "change", handler )` in the first two variations, and `.trigger( "change" )` in the third.
>
> The `change` event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/nPkPw/3/

Using chaining: http://jsfiddle.net/nPkPw/5/
i.e. `$("input[type='checkbox']").trigger('change').attr('checked', 'checked');`

Comment: seems a little verbose to simulate a click

Comment: for future reference, I had to put trigger after the attr so my script to see what the change was.

Comment: trigger should occur after the attr change not before
$("input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', 'checked').trigger('change');

Comment: Man... wish i could find this 4 hours ago when i was searching - (google are you listening) - "toggle one filter parameter isotop js". Thanks mate.

Answer (score 10):

This isn't surprising, but I guess you could as this to the list of non-effect [in the msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536912%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

- "This event is fired when the contents are committed and not while
  the value is changing."
- "The onchange event does not fire when the
  selected option of the select object is changed programmatically."

You could always just `.click()` it [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/crF93/3/)