# Am I able to change the state of a checkbox with Jasmine?

Tags: jquery, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to write a test that checks a value after the checkbox is checked but it keeps returning a failed test.

I thought it would be as simple as using jQuery to set the value of it to checked, but it doesn't seem to be working.

My input has a change event attached to it:

```
$("input#p1").change(function()
{
    pprompts.settings.aiGoesFirst = $(this).is(":checked");
});
```

My test:

```
it('should allow the user to choose who goes first', function()
{
    // the user goes first by default - PASSES
    expect(pprompts.settings.aiGoesFirst).toBe(false);

    // trigger the checkbox for ai to go first and check if AI is going first - FAILS
    $("input#p1").attr("checked","checked");
    expect(pprompts.settings.aiGoesFirst).toBe(true);
});
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think setting checked will trigger the change event.  See, for example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159214/why-does-dynamically-changing-a-checkbox-not-trigger-a-form-change-event

Comment: Thanks for that. I've updated my script to change the attribute and then trigger change, but it still fails.