# Read-only field not changing after assignment

Tags: javascript

In my HTML form I have a read-only field that contains the fee based on a variety of selections and radio boxes.

```
<input name="AdultFee_1" type="text" class="tabfont_right" id="AdultFee_1" value="0" size="10"  readonly="readonly" />
```

The following javascript (shortened for brevity) is used to assign a fee and display it in AdultFee_1.

```
function GetField (FieldID)
{
  return document.getElementById(FieldID);   
} //endfunction GetField (FieldID)

function CalcAdultFee (EntryID)
{
var fee=0.00;

// Retrieve data values from the form.
var AdultRegType = GetField ("AdultRegType_" + EntryID);
var AdultTSCredit = GetField ("AdultTSCredit_" + EntryID);
var AdultPrayerRetreat = GetField ("AdultPrayerRetreat_" + EntryID);
var AdultFee = GetField ("AdultFee_" + EntryID);

// Check that the current date is before the early-bird cutoff.
if (new Date() < new Date(2012, 8, 29)) {

  // Determine the fee based on the registration type selected. Add costs for Temple School 
  // Credit and Adult Prayer Retreat if selected. If the user is only going to the Friday
  // Friday prayer retreat, do not add the additional option if selected.
  switch (AdultRegType.value) {
      case "Adult Registration": 
        fee = 85.00 + parseFloat((AdultTSCredit.checked) ? 10 : 0) + parseFloat((AdultPrayerRetreat.checked) ? 35: 0);
        break;
      case "College Student": 
        fee = 25.00 + parseFloat((AdultTSCredit.checked) ? 10 : 0) + parseFloat((AdultPrayerRetreat.checked) ? 35: 0); 
        break;
      case "IHQ/Field Staff": 
        fee = 42.50 + parseFloat((AdultTSCredit.checked) ? 10 : 0) + parseFloat((AdultPrayerRetreat.checked) ? 35: 0); 
        break;
      case "ONLY Friday Prayer Retreat": 
        fee = 35.00 + parseFloat((AdultTSCredit.checked) ? 10 : 0); 
        break;
      default:
        fee = 0.00;
  } //endswitch (RegType)

// elseif (new Date() < new Date(2012, 8, 29))
}//endif (new Date() < new Date(2012, 8, 29))

AdultFee.value = fee;
CalcGrandTotal();

} //endfunction CalcAdultFee (RegType)
```

The issue in IE8 is that the new value does not appear on the form until a user clicks on a field. This seems to work well in IE9, FF12, and Safari. I must be missing something. What do I do?

Comment: What triggers the `CalcAdultFee` call?

Comment: CalcAdultFee is called within ValidateAdultRegType(EntryID) which is called by the form in one of three onchange events.<input name="AdultPrayerRetreat_1" type="checkbox" id="AdultPrayerRetreat_1" value="Yes" onchange="CalcAdultFee(1)"

Comment: Sounds like you should call it when the page is loaded... perhaps the other browsers do validation when the page is loaded, but IE8 does not?

Comment: Change events aren't triggered until the `<input>` loses focus: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7055771/479863

Comment: @MU, do you think I could make the focus go on the fee field to force it to change and then set focus on the next field?

Comment: You might be able to manually trigger a change event at the right time rather than trying to mess around with the focus.