# Trigger function when user changes input value (backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I just started with backbone.js and is currently making a page which has a div `#listing_filter` containing text input elements and a table showing some listings fetched from a RESTful backend (PHP/Codeigniter). The values in the text input will act as filters to narrow down the results retrieved by the server.

**Problem:** Whenever the value in any of the text boxes changes, I want the browser to GET another set of results based on the filter values. Below is my attempt, where the `updateFilter` function does not fire even though the text input value was changed. Any ideas what went wrong?

Another question will be whether I should put the contents of `#listing_filter` into a template, or just hardcode it into the main body HTML? Thanks!

**JS Code**

```
window.ListingFilterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'updateFilter');
    },

    events: {
        'change input' : 'updateFilter'
    },

    updateFilter: function() {
        console.log('hey');
    }

});

// Router

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'listings',
    },

    listings: function() {
       //... some other code here
        this.listingFilterView = new ListingFilterView();
    }
});
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="listing_filter">
    Price: <input type="text" id="listing_filter_price" />
    Beds: <input type="text" id="listing_filter_bedroom" />
    Baths: <input type="text" id="listing_filter_bathroom" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Backbone view will only respond to events on the view's `el` or on elements that are inside its `el`. By default, the view's `el` is just [an empty `<div>`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-el) and you're not telling the view to use anything else.

You can tell the view which `el` to use (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/5yXcU/1/):

```
new ListingFilterView({ el: $('#listing_filter') })
// Or like this:
new ListingFilterView({ el: '#listing_filter' })
```

or you can let the view attach itself to that element using [`setElement`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-setElement) (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/APEfa/1/):

```
initialize: function() {
    this.setElement($('#listing_filter'));
    // or setElement('#listing_filter')
}
```

or set the `el` when you define the view (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/nyTZU/):

```
window.ListingFilterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#listing_filter',
    //...
});
```

Once that's out of the way, you'll need to understand that an `<input>` won't trigger a change event [until it loses focus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7055771/479863) so you'll have to wait for the user to tab-out of the input or switch to listening for `keypress` events and using a timer to detect when they've stopped typing.

Comment: or simpler: `window.ListingFilterView = Backbone.View.extend({ el: '#listing_filter' // ... }`. btw, you don't need to pass jQuery object to the `el` attribute, you could pass just a string: `var v = new V({ el: '#listing_filter' });`

Comment: @user1248256: True enough, old habits and all that.