# jquery: why .change doesn't listen when I change the selected option in a select

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this listener :

```
$("#chosenpro").change(function(){ ...});
```

But it doesn't hear when I change the selected value using this in another function:

```
$('#chosenpro option:first').attr("selected", "selected");
$('#chosenpro').selectmenu("refresh", true);
```

Any hint ?

I am working with jquery-mobile.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GCf3y/2/

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055729/onchange-event-not-fire-when-the-change-come-from-antoher-function

Comment: @Schleis thanks but I am looking for a jquery solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to trigger `change` programmatically.

```
$('#chosenpro').trigger('change');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GCf3y/

Comment: Thanks but it's not working yet. I am using jquery-mobile (sorry I forgot to mention). I modified the fiddle to represent my problem more closely: http://jsfiddle.net/GCf3y/2/