# Getting selected string from autocompleted input box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm building a form where the first field (text input) is auto-completed from a MySQL table, and the second one (a dropdown) is populated as a result of the choice made in the first one. The autocomplete works fine, but I can't figure out how to get the chosen option from it; instead, I'm only getting the search string that I actually typed (e.g., 'eggn' instead of the 'Eggnog' option that I picked); in fact, the 'onchange' function fires off before the selected option even gets copied to the input box.

Really would appreciate some help with this one.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#name").autocomplete({
            source: 'getautocomplete.php',
            minLength: 2
        });
    });

    function ajaxfunction(key) {
        alert(key);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'get_units1.php?key=' + key,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#sub").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<form method="post">
    <input type='text' id='name' onchange="ajaxfunction(this.value)">
    <select id="sub">
        <option value="">Choose the amount</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit'>
    <input type='reset'>
</form>
```

Comment: Huh. Weird - removing it (or having it there) doesn't seem to do anything different. I've removed it now, of course; thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable autocomplete features, I used one dummy array as the source of the autocomplete.

If I understand your question correctly, bind the event=`select` will be better than `change`.

The autocomplete of below codes works fine. You can try your test cases at the snippet, then pay an attention on when the event will be triggered for `change` and `select`.

The event=`change` will be triggered when out of focus.

The event=`select` will be triggered when select one item of autocomplete.

**Updated:** Thanks the comment from @IncredibleHat, we should get rid of `onchange="onChangeAutocomplete(this.value)"` when already reference JQuery UI.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var availableTags = [ "ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","C","C++","Clojure","COBOL","ColdFusion","Erlang","Fortran","Groovy","Haskell","Java","JavaScript","Lisp","Perl","PHP","Python","Ruby","Scala","Scheme"
    ];
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#name").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
              console.log('[select]the string in autocomplete: ' + ui.item.label + '-' + ui.item.value);
            },
            //As the comment from @IncredibleHat, get rid of using old way to bind onchange.
            //follow the instructions of Jquery UI Autocomplete to bind the event like below
            change: function( event, ui) {
              console.log('[change1]the string in autocomplete: ' + ui.item.label + '-' + ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    });

    function onChangeAutocomplete(key)
    {
        console.log('[change2]the string in autocomplete: ' + key);
        /*$.ajax({
            url: 'get_units1.php?key=' + key,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#sub").html(data);
            }
        });*/
    }

    </script>

    <form method="post">
    <input type='text' id='name'" onchange="onChangeAutocomplete(this.value)">
    <select id="sub">
    <option value="">Choose the amount</option>
    </select>
    <input type='submit'><input type='reset'>
    </form>
```

Comment: That was it - THANK YOU! Looks like I'd been staring at the wrong part of the code for too long... this makes sense, of course.

Comment: @IncredibleHat, old `onchange` will be triggered when out of focus instead of every KEYPRESS, check this [onchange event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055729/onchange-event-not-fire-when-the-change-come-from-another-function)