# Can javascript tell the difference between user input and dynamic update?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I need to be able to use javascript/jquery to update a field. But I need to be able to check whether the input was updated manually by the user or if the input was dynamically updated using a `document.getElementById().value`.

`onChange()` method seems to execute no matter if the user modified the control, or if I dynamically updated the control.

Any help? Is there something similar to `onChange()` that only executes when a user manually types/edits a control?

Comment: No, a "change" event is not fired when JavaScript updates the `.value` of an `<input>`.

Comment: What about [`onFocus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onfocus)? For the user is necessary to focus on a target to edit it, while for an dynamic update I think no (I'm not sure about this, but maybe it can help)

Comment: @Pointy you are correct. change events are not fired when javascript updates the .value. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually edit the `.value` of an input element, and as long as the element was not focussed by the user, an `onChange event` is not fired by most browsers.

Comment: This is correct. I was incorrect in thinking onchange was triggered without user input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OnKeyUp / OnKeyPress might be the event you are looking fo.

[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)
The input event is fired every time the value of the element changes. This is unlike the change event, which only fires when the value is committed, such as by pressing the enter key, selecting a value from a list of options, and the like.

Also, see this link [onchange event not fire when the change come from another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055729/onchange-event-not-fire-when-the-change-come-from-another-function)

Comment: The premise of the question is incorrect. No "change" event is fired when JavaScript updates an element value.

Comment: For that thing, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055729/onchange-event-not-fire-when-the-change-come-from-another-function